# Why wont Bash wait for read when used with Curl?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, pipe, sh

I wrote a [Bash script to congfigure Git](https://raw.github.com/gist/419201/gitconfig.bash). It uses the `read` builtin, but when I do:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/gist/419201/gitconfig.bash)
```

It doesn't wait for me to enter input. How do I get it to wait?

Comment: how enter input? you're redirecting stdin with < aren't you?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I guess I was... What do those arrows even mean in this context?

Comment: the single < means "redirect standard input". the <(something) construct is called Process Substitution, search for that on the Bash manpage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested it whitout the `<` as jcomeau_ictx suggested and it worked.

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/gist/419201/gitconfig.bash | head -n 3)
```

Note: I used `head -3` to stop execution after the read.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx I posted an answer simply using your hint, now I get credit for it, im sorry about that.

Comment: MattDiPasquale, get rid of the "head -n 3", that was just for Lynch's test

Comment: @MattDiPasquale yes its because of the head -n3 I did not want to execute your script on my enviroment. I was just testing the read part.

Comment: never *ever* feel bad about that. actually you read more into my answer than intended, taught me something, and vastly improved on my answer. a big win all around. StackOverflow is a great medium for this type of thing!

Comment: Oops. I just realized that and deleted my comment. Sweet, it works!

Answer (score 3):

You may try to `read` directly from the controlling terminal `/dev/tty` to re-enable user input in case stdin is already redirected, i.e. file descriptor 0 is not opened on a terminal.

You may even use the `-t` option to the `test` command to handle such a situation programmatically (see `help test` or `man test`).

```
read git_name < /dev/tty       # per-command I/O redirection
#read git_name < /dev/console  # alternative

exec 0</dev/tty               # script-wide I/O redirection
read git_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use stdin, you'd need to fetch the file, say to /tmp, then `bash /tmp/gitconfig.bash`. The way you're doing it now, you're redirecting stdin, and Unix doesn't have a separate file descriptor for command input like VMS does.

Comment: No, but you can tell `read` to use one, and run `exec` to redirect `/dev/tty` into it before running the script.

Comment: you mean exec 1</dev/tty at the beginning of the script? seems that would work. my first thought was how to get it to work without modification.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams would you please share example code for how I'd do that in an answer?